# Script to match password with database in magento 1.7 enterprise

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying with this:

```
$password = md5($_GET['password']);
echo "Password: ".$pass = Mage::getSingleton('core/encryption')->getHash($password,'abcd1234');

echo "<br/>";

echo "ORIGINAL PASSWORD IS ba9791a5dec550a3a6cc3f4e748fd588:OG";
echo "<br/>";
```

But unfortunately the password is not matching with the Magento's

Magento Version is 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Mage::helper('core')->getHash($password, 2);
```

But if you want to match password with DB use:

```
Mage::helper('core')->validateHash($password, $hash);
```

Comment: and what is $hash? what will be the value for it?

Comment: It's a user's hash that stored in DB.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php

```
public function validateHash($password, $hash)
{
    $hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
    switch (count($hashArr)) {
        case 1:
            return $this->hash($password) === $hash;
        case 2:
            return $this->hash($password . $hashArr[1]) === $hashArr[0];
    }
    Mage::throwException('Invalid hash.');
}
```

The password before apply md5 concatenate passowrd+SALT

you will see the SALT at the end of the password_hash in database :
0836de2601523547b3365c4d20e9012a:I4

I4 is the salt!!